# In Drupal 7 how do you create different layouts for views containing lists of teasers and the full node content?

Tags: css, drupal-7

I'm building my first Drupal 7 Website and have gone through and created Content Types and views of them, then included them in Panels. The views show the teaser display of a particular node as a paged group. I've gone and styled all the views so they look nice using CSS and now I'm coming to styling the content types, i.e. the Full content that people get to when they click on the teaser title/image, but the CSS I've applied to the views teasers is also being applied to the Full Content. I'm a bit stuck, as from looking using Firebug, it seems to be using the same classes in the Full Content as in the Teasers. What can I do to fix this, bearing in mind, I'm not a PHP programmer?? Also prefereably I wouldn't like to have to redo all my CSS on the views. Any ideas? Sorry if my naming is a bit out, I'm more used to SharePoint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added your own content type, the body should include that particular node type in the list of classes on body. For example, if you had a content type Event, your body on that content item view will be something along the lines of body class="node-type-event".

You could latch on to those classes, to override your content node pages, i.e...

```
<style>
.node-type-event p {
color: red;
}
</style>
```

...should affect only those nodes of the specific content type.

Hoepfully does the trick, without wiping out your teaser CSS.

Comment: The best answer I can find after looking again is to add a variant via the Panels module for the node Content Type and apply CSS using this. I saved the CSS I'd applied to the views by preceding the node-content classes with the CSS classes I've added already for the Views. Thanks for your help.